# Invoking function with variable length of arguments

Tags: scheme, racket

I have a function that takes a list of arguments with variable length. And depend on 
its length, i have to invoke another function, but with different length of arguments. You see the function below:

```
  (define (set-contents . args)
   (define columns-length (length args))
        (cond
          ((= columns-length 1) 
           (send output-list set (empty-list rows-length) (get-nth-item columns-as-list 0)))
          ((= columns-length 2) 
           (send output-list set (empty-list rows-length) (get-nth-item columns-as-list 0) (get-nth-item columns-as-list 1)))
          ((= columns-length 3) 
           (send output-list set (empty-list rows-length) (get-nth-item columns-as-list 0) (get-nth-item columns-as-list 1) (get-nth-item columns-as-list 2)))
          ((= columns-length 4) 
           (send output-list set (empty-list rows-length) (get-nth-item columns-as-list 0) (get-nth-item columns-as-list 1) (get-nth-item columns-as-list 2) (get-nth-item columns-as-list 3)))
```

This cond clause can be still longer. It is working but absolutely no proper.

Is there a better way to fill up this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, a direct translation of the idea is as follows:

```
(define (set-contents . args)
  (send/apply output-list set (empty-list rows-length)
                              (for/list ((i (length args)))
                                (get-nth-item columns-as-list i))))
```

But, since you're not actually using the arguments other than getting the argument count, that seems pretty fishy. What are you trying to do?

Comment: thanks! well, there is a list-box% and depend on the number of columns, i'm sending in each argument a list of values for that column. And send/apply and for/list functions didn't work.

Comment: Are you using a different language from `racket`? If so, all bets are off. Or, to put it more kindly, please switch to the `racket` language in order to have a much nicer programming experience.

Comment: Sorry it was my fault. It has worked so good! Thank you @Chris Jester-Young !

Answer (score 0):

Use apply?

```
(define (set-contents . args)
  (define columns-length (length args))
  (apply send (append (list output-list set '()) 
                      (take column-length columns-as-list))))

(define (take num lst)
  (cond ((< num 1) '())
        ((null? lst) (error "Cannot TAKE from the empty list")
        (else (cons (car lst) (take (- num 1) (cdr lst))))))
```

Sure beats being a human compiler

Comment: `send` is a macro, and you cannot `apply` it directly. That's why I used `send/apply` in my answer. Also, Racket has `take` out of the box, you should not redefine it.